# What's an expression that describes a statement that ignores nuance and generalizes abusively to all cases?

Tags: expressions

What's an expression that describes the fact that a statement ignores all nuance in an issue and generalizes abusively to all cases?

Sorry for the clumsy question. Here's an example, that may be charged, but I think most clearly conveys the kind of statement I'm interested in:

> All blacks are criminals.

Comment: Perhaps a [_stereotype_](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stereotype)?

Comment: A sweeping generalisation?

Comment: All people who make sweeping generalizations should be shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to describe a statement like

> All monkeys have long tails

or

> Real men eat quiche

you can say it is a

[***blanket statement***](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/blanket)

> → blanket statement/rule/ban etc
>
> blanket: adjective [only before a noun]: affecting or including everything or everyone.  *The authorities have introduced a blanket ban on tobacco advertising in all public places.  The agency is offering a blanket settlement to all groups.*

*(Longman Business Dictionary)*

but you can also say it's a

***one-size-fits-all statement***

or it's an *oversimplification* or an *overgeneralization*.

But if you want to focus on *offensive* statements, then we need something stronger, such as:

***racist claim***

or

***offensive stereotyping***

If you narrow down what you're looking for, I'll give you some more definitions.

Comment: Now that you mention it, blanket statement is exactly what I was looking for. Great answer.